# Only capture digits instead of the other text in input for a regex like below

Tags: java

Currently this regular expression:

```
^(?:\\S+\\s+)*?(\\S+)\\s+(?:No\\.\\s+)?(\\S+)(?:\\s+\\(.*?\\))?$
```

captures `418&mdash;FINAL` in group number 2 for an input like:

```
String text="H.B. 418&mdash;FINAL VERSION";
```

How do I change this regular expression to only capture the number (digits) of "418" in group2 ? 
EDIT:

I'd still like to capture "H.B." in a preceding group.

Comment: Replace group 2 with `((\\d+)\\S+)`. This will capture the digits in group 3. All other groups will be shifted by one, so `(?:No\\.\\s+)` will become group 4, etc.

Comment: @ajb Thanks. I'm not a regex ninja, so I didn't know about the `?:`, but I could still diagnose this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the boundaries of the second group to only include the digits. To also save the "H.B." part, add paranthesis around that part too:

```
^(?:(\\S+)\\s+)*?(\\d+)\\S+\\s+(?:No\\.\\s+)?(\\S+)(?:\\s+\\(.*?\\))?$
```

Comment: This also works, if you don't need the entire version number.

Comment: But I'd still like to capture "H.B." in a group. After using this expression it captures 418 in group1

Comment: @Phoenix: Updated to get "H.B." in group 1 and the number in group 2.

Comment: @Keppil the first `(?:\\S+\\s+)*?` wouldn't capture anything unless there was a "No" somewhere in the string or more than one word before the digit sequence, so I think it shouldn't have been removed.  (Note the ? after the * which means "as few as possible matches".)  Also, your answer would include the following space in the capture group, which is not what is wanted.  The following `(\\S+)` would have captured the "H.B." like OP wanted.

Comment: @ajb: You are mistaken, the first group finds a match for the given text, and that doesn't contain `No`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your exact requirements are (your regex is looking for an optional "No." but you haven't given any examples).  But this will work on the example you give:

```
^(?:\\S+\\s+)*?(\\S+)\\s+(?:No\\.\\s+)?(\\d+).*(?:\\s+\\(.*?\\))?$
```

assuming you don't need the text following the digits.  That is, just change the second \S to \d.  I also added .* after this to match any remaining characters following the digits up to an optional parenthesized part (without capturing them, but you can capture them if you want to).

Comment: OK, I fixed it and tested it.